# Debugging with Eclipse - Tomcat server window disappears on initiating Debug in Eclispe

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, batch-file, tomcat

I am trying to remote debug my application. This is what i have done till now.
    1 - environment variable set  - JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
    2 - environment variable set  - JPDA_ADDRESS=4000
    3 - In startup.bat file, the following line

```
    call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
    is replaced with   
    call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

4 - in the setenv.bat file, the following line has been added

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000, suspend=n"
```

In Eclipse, In debug configuration window, I set the port to 4000, pointed the source. Restarted the eclipse.

***Behavior***
    When is start the Tomcat, the Only following line is printed on the server console, nothing else.

```
*Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4000*
```

When i go into Eclipse, do in debug configuration and press ***debug*** , the tomcat(server) window disappears. I have no logs and no clue what is happening.

**Note**
    I am using windows 8.1 , Eclipse Luna, Java 7

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in catalina.bat
set JPDA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9876

in the end of startup.bat make sure jpda is present startup.bat file
call "%EXECUTABLE%" **jpda start** %CMD_LINE_ARGS%